# I can not type on the div tag if I click on the content of :before

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have created this div for getting comment input from user.

```
<div
 role="textarea"
 aria-expanded={false}
 contentEditable
 ref={commentBoxRef}
 className={modalStyle.commentInput}
 onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
/>
```

Here is the css.

```
.commentInput {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #242424;
    border-radius: 8px;
    resize: none;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.commentInput:empty:not(:focus):before {
    content: "Type comment";
    color: grey;
}
```

I have shown placeholder with css. The issue is when I click on the placeholder I can not type on the input. Though the input fires focus event but I can not type at there. If I click outside of the placeholder only then I am able to type.

I am expecting to be able to write on the input even if I click on the placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `pointer-events: none;` with that pseudo-element content. This will ignore the click events and clicks the elements underneath it.

```css
.commentInput {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    outline: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #242424;
    border-radius: 8px;
    resize: none;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    color: white;
}

.commentInput:not(:focus):empty:before {
    content: "Type comment";
    color: grey;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div  class="commentInput" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, it fixed the issue. Learned a new css trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix. The issue was when I click on the placeholder, the before element gets unmounted. Thats why the input focus getting blur again. Now I have added another css which will set the content empty string so that it doesn't get unmounted. Now it works fine.

```css
.commentInput {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #242424;
    border-radius: 8px;
    resize: none;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.commentInput:not(:focus):empty:before {
    content: "Type comment";
    color: grey;
}

.commentInput:focus:before {
    content: "";
}
```